# Is there a way to auto scale EC2 instances based on SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-auto-scaling

I'm currently trying to figure out if it's possible to automatically scale an EC2 instance based on the SQS queue. The main goal is to reduce costs. So the scaling should be something like this:

1. If the SQS queue is 0 for let's say 60 minutes the EC2 instance should scale down to 0.
2. If the SQS queue has the same amount of pending events for more than 2-3 minutes -- scale up to 1.

Is this possible and how would you do go about it with terraform?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Autoscaling Groups and SQS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, the way to create such a configuration is [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html), with examples of using AWS CLI to achieve that. However, since you were asking about terraform specifically, there is pretty much the same [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/5.11.0/docs/resources/autoscaling_policy#create-target-tracking-scaling-policy-using-metric-math) as in the AWS docs, only in terraform. The only thing I would change in that example is e.g., referencing the ASG and SQS using the implicit reference instead of hardcoding the name of the ASG and the queue, respecitvely. So for example:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foobar" {
  name_prefix   = "foobar"
  image_id      = "ami-1a2b3c"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
  desired_capacity   = 0
  max_size           = 1
  min_size           = 0

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.foobar.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "bar" {
  name = "mysqs-queue"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "example" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.bar.name
  name                   = "foo"
  policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  target_tracking_configuration {
    target_value = 100
    customized_metric_specification {
      metrics {
        label = "Get the queue size (the number of messages waiting to be processed)"
        id    = "m1"
        metric_stat {
          metric {
            namespace   = "AWS/SQS"
            metric_name = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
            dimensions {
              name  = "QueueName"
              value = aws_sqs_queue.bar.name
            }
          }
          stat = "Sum"
        }
        return_data = false
      }
      metrics {
        label = "Get the group size (the number of InService instances)"
        id    = "m2"
        metric_stat {
          metric {
            namespace   = "AWS/AutoScaling"
            metric_name = "GroupInServiceInstances"
            dimensions {
              name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
              value = aws_autoscaling_group.bar.name
            }
          }
          stat = "Average"
        }
        return_data = false
      }
      metrics {
        label       = "Calculate the backlog per instance"
        id          = "e1"
        expression  = "m1 / m2"
        return_data = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `target_value` is set to `100` in this example, but you can set it to any number of messages in the queue which you would find as a threshold above which the number of instances should scale.

Comment: I was about to suggest you post it as an answer. I was looking for those docs. Thanks for answering the question!  :)

Comment: No worries, I thought it might be shown as a complete example in the terraform docs, but since it wasn't I figured it might be useful to have it all glued together. :)

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the terraform and aws docs are a bit misleading. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: @MarkoE:  Thanks for continuously helping us with great answers! It's been a few times now that you've provided really helpful answers to our questions!

Comment: Always happy to help when I can @carlspring. :)

Comment: What happens if `m2` is zero? (i.e. divide by zero).  I'm getting an error 'One or more data-points have been dropped due to non-numeric values', which I presume is because m2 is zero.  I've tried `expression  = "m1 / IF(m2>0, m2, 1)"` and that doesn't fix it