# Auto-scaling group based on SQS depth

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-auto-scaling

I am writing Terraform code that does the following: sets up S3 bucket and S3 event notifications, also Lambda that is being triggered by S3 notifications. Then it sends the messages to SQS. And then there is an auto-scaling group based on the SQS depth (using the formula number of messages / number of instances) with a cap of 5 instances (so never more that 5 instances running in ASG). I created the auto-scaling policy for that and read that this type of policy can trigger itself and doesn't need an alarm (?). `terraform apply` runs successfully but then I test in AWS by sending messages in my SQS but don't see any instances being added in the ASG. What am doing wrong / missing?

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "file_checker_sqs_queue" {
  name                      = var.sqs_queue_name
  max_message_size          = 256000
  message_retention_seconds = 86400
  visibility_timeout_seconds = 30
    receive_wait_time_seconds = 10
  }

 data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
   state = "available"
   # Only retrieve the main AZs, no local zones.
   filter {
     name = "opt-in-status"
     values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
   }
 }

 data "aws_ami" "audio_ami" {
   most_recent = true

   filter {
     name   = "image-id"
     values = ["ami-067d1e60475437ey2"]
   }
 }

 resource "aws_launch_configuration" "audio_asg_launch_config" {
   name_prefix   = var.launch_config_name_prefix
   image_id      = data.aws_ami.audio_ami.id
   instance_type = "t2.micro"

   lifecycle {
     create_before_destroy = true
   }
 }

 resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "audio_auto_scaling_group" {
   availability_zones        = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
   name                      = var.asg_name
   max_size                  = 5
   min_size                  = 0
   health_check_grace_period = 300
   health_check_type         = "EC2"
   force_delete              = true
   launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.audio_asg_launch_config.name
 }

 resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "asg_audio_scale_up_policy" {
   autoscaling_group_name = var.asg_name
   name                   = var.asg_policy_name
   policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"
   depends_on             = [ aws_autoscaling_group.audio_auto_scaling_group ]
      
   target_tracking_configuration {
      target_value = 1
      customized_metric_specification {
        metrics {
          label = "Get the queue size (the number of messages waiting to be processed)"
          id    = "m1"
          metric_stat {
            metric {
              namespace   = "AWS/SQS"
              metric_name = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
              dimensions {
              name  = "QueueName"
              value = var.sqs_queue_name
           }
        }
        stat = "Sum"
      }
      return_data = false
    }
    metrics {
      label = "Get the group size (the number of InService instances)"
       id    = "m2"
       metric_stat {
         metric {
           namespace   = "AWS/AutoScaling"
           metric_name = "GroupInServiceInstances"
           dimensions {
             name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
             value = var.asg_name
           }
         }
         stat = "Average"
       }
       return_data = false
     }
     metrics {
       label       = "Calculate the backlog per instance"
       id          = "e1"
       expression  = "IF(m2 == 0, m1, m1 / m2)"
       return_data = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update: tried to address the comments and here are the updated parts of my code (still nothing is happening in my ASG after I send messages in SQS):

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "audio_asg_launch_template" {
  name_prefix   = var.launch_config_name_prefix
  image_id      = data.aws_ami.audio_ami.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "audio_auto_scaling_group" {
  availability_zones        = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  name                      = var.asg_name
  max_size                  = var.asg_max_size
  min_size                  = var.asg_min_size
  desired_capacity = 0
  health_check_grace_period = var.asg_health_check_grace_period
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  force_delete              = true
  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.audio_asg_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }
}
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "asg_audio_scale_up_policy" {
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.audio_auto_scaling_group.name
  name                   = var.asg_policy_name
  policy_type            = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  
  target_tracking_configuration {
    target_value = 1
    customized_metric_specification {
      metrics {
        label = "Get the queue size (the number of messages waiting to be processed)"
        id    = "m1"
        metric_stat {
          metric {
            namespace   = "AWS/SQS"
            metric_name = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
            dimensions {
              name  = "QueueName"
              value = aws_sqs_queue.file_checker_sqs_queue.name
            }
          }
          stat = "Sum"
        }
        return_data = false
      }
      metrics {
        label = "Get the group size (the number of InService instances)"
        id    = "m2"
        metric_stat {
          metric {
            namespace   = "AWS/AutoScaling"
            metric_name = "GroupInServiceInstances"
            dimensions {
              name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
              value = aws_autoscaling_group.audio_auto_scaling_group.name
            }
          }
          stat = "Average"
        }
        return_data = false
      }
      metrics {
        label       = "Calculate the backlog per instance"
        id          = "e1"
        expression  = "IF(m2 == 0, m1, m1 / m2)"
        return_data = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76874738/is-there-a-way-to-auto-scale-ec2-instances-based-on-sqs-queue/76875292#76875292?

Comment: Not really, the code in the link seems to look like mine but then I try and it doesn't actually scale

Comment: It does, but there are some subtle differences. For example, you have no desired capacity defined. Also, the answer shows using implicit dependencies between resources, while you are using variables, so that could help as well.

Comment: But I don't think I need the desired capacity? I just need it to scale up and in and never be more that 5 but that should be controlled by the max_size property in the ASG?

Comment: @MarkoE I adjusted my code based on the link you provided (added the desired capacity, launch template instead of launch config and implicit dependencies instead of variables). resources were added successfully, but then I sent SQS messages and nothing happened in my ASG. Anything else I might be missing? I'll add the updated code below my first code block

Comment: I'm not sure that setting the target_value to 1 makes sense. Take a look at the explanation of how to use target value from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html#:~:text=As%20an%20example,the%20target%20value.).

Comment: It does, it means that we want 1 message per instance. I found a solution, will post it now

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Everything is okay with the policy itself, the issue was that ASG doesn't enable metrics by default. Once I included it into my code - everything started working. So the initial code in my question stays the same and we're only adding the following:

```js
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "audio_auto_scaling_group" {
  # the rest of the code stays the same

  # Enabling metrics collection for AutoScaling Group
  enabled_metrics = ["GroupInServiceInstances"]
}
```